# Update SQL Database based on matched ID in Dataframe

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, dataframe

I have the dataframe below with the respective values and would like to update my SQL Database Server if the ID matches with my dataframe

df dataframe

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 9 |
| 456 | 11 |

SQL Database Server, table1

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 456 | 62 |
| 623 | 41 |
| 123 | 3 |
| 563 | 67 |

After updating, I want my SQL Database Server to look like this where you'll notice that ID 123 & 456 has been given a new value based on my dataframe.

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 456 | 11 |
| 623 | 41 |
| 123 | 9 |
| 563 | 67 |

Anyone knows how I could utilise this in my query when executing?

```
query = DELETE/UPDATE table table1 where ID = ID IN DATAFRAME

conn.execute(query)
```

Comment: How are you connecting to sql-server? Also, are you dealing with just a few or 1000s of records in a Pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a parameter list(`df_list`) along with a DML statement, and arrange the order of columns due to the appearance within the statement. In this case those two arguments(`id` and `value`) should be reversely ordered such as

```
cur=con.cursor()
sql = "UPDATE [table1] SET [value] = ? WHERE [id] = ?"
cols = df.columns.tolist()
df_list = df[cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]].values.tolist()                                                         
cur.executemany(sql,df_list)
cur.close()
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make corelated query as follows:

```
update table1 t1
   set t1.value = (select df.value from df where df.id = t1.id)
where exists (select 1 from df where df.id = t1.id);
```

OR use `Inner join` in `update` as follows:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.value = d.value -- , another column updates here 
FROM table1 as t
INNER JOIN df as d ON t.id = d.id;
```

Comment: I should have clarified that that I want to update the entire row (assuming there are more columns in the table) and would need to use sqlalchemy in this case to execute the query

Comment: You can update any number of columns. see the updated answer